# How to return the correct CurrencyManager when binding to TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am using a `DataBoundTreeView` control in which nodes reflect the primary key for parent nodes and the foreign key for child nodes. Now, the `IBindingList` for the `CurrencyManager` is filtered based on the selected parent node however, i cannot seem to get the filter to work after adding a new row to the dataset using a `BindingSource`. When getting a `CurrencyManager` through the method below and adding it to a new node, clicking on that node selects the first node in the treeview because the filterValue (which i cannot change) is set to the first node! Is there a step i could be missing? Here's an example of what i have tried:

```
 CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[jartrekDataSet, "KeyMaster.MyKeyRelate"];

 IBindingList childList = ((IBindingList)((BoundTreeNode)DataBoundTree.TreeView.SelectedNode).CurrencyManager.List);
```

I am using the `DataBoundTreeView` from the following article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9241/DataBound-TreeView-Control?msg=5355916

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well for what its worth I actually figured it out! I have literally been banging my head off the desk trying to fix this and it came down to one thing. I noticed that the namespace for my DataBoundTreeView was actually added as MyTreeView.DataBoundTreeView. I must have added it incorrectly when i first started using it. Could this extra path it took effected how the events were fired? Just curious. You can delete this question if need be but this definitely stumped me.

Comment: One more thing    ``CurrencyManager cm = ((BoundTreeNode)DataBoundTree.TreeView.SelectedNode).CurrencyManager;``  Now allows me to select the correct `CurrencyManager` for the selected node in the treeview so i can now add a new node when adding a row. Ok im done. Just super stoked! Thanks!